# Equivalence of Hölder norms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, holder-spaces

> Let $0 <\alpha \leq 1$. Define 
>   $$
> |f|_1= \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|+ \sup_{x,h\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|^{\alpha}}\right|$$
>   $$
> |f|_2= \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|+ \sup_{x,h\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{|h|^{\alpha}}\right|
> $$
>   for $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
>
> Prove that for every $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $ f\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ there exists a constant $c \geq 1 $  s.t. 
>   $$
> c^{-1}|f|_2\leq |f|_1\leq c|f|_2 
> $$ 
>   Discuss the same question for $\alpha = 1$.

Can anyone help me and give me a hint...?

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in the supremum but $f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so $d=1$?

Comment: oh, I didnt notice that before. I think $ x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is meant in the supremum.

Answer (score 2):

First it is easy to see that, 
$$\|f\|_{\infty}  +\left|\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{|h|^{\alpha}}\right| 
=\|f\|_\infty+ \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x) -(f(x)-f(x-h))}{|h|^{\alpha}}\right|\\\le \|f\|_\infty+\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^\alpha} \right|+\left|\frac{(f(x)-f(x-h))}{|h|^{\alpha}}\right|  \le 2|f|_1 $$

Which implies, by taking the supremum that, $$|f|_2 \le 2|f|_1$$
this means that, if we define the embedding

Next we consider $z= x+k$ and $h=2k$ hence, $x+h =z+k$ and $x =z-k$

Then, for $0<\alpha <1,$
$$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|^{\alpha}}\right| = \left|\frac{f(z+k)-2f(z)+f(z-k) +\color{red}{2 [f(z) -f(z-k)]}}{|2k|^{\alpha}}\right|\\ \le 2^{-\alpha} \left|\frac{f(z+k)-2f(z)+f(z-k)}{|k|^{\alpha}}\right| + 2^{1-\alpha} \left|\frac{\color{red}{ [f(z) -f(z-k)]}}{|k|^{\alpha}}\right|$$

passing through the supremum yields,
  $$ |f|_1 \le 2^{-\alpha}|f|_2 +2^{1-\alpha} |f|_1 \implies (1-2^{1-\alpha})|f|_1 \le 2^{-\alpha}|f|_2 $$
that is

$$ |f|_1 \le \frac{2^{-\alpha}}{(1-2^{1-\alpha})}|f|_2 $$

Let $$\color{blue}{c=\max(2,\frac{2^{-\alpha}}{(1-2^{1-\alpha})})}. $$
Thus, $$c^{-1}|f|_2\le |f|_1 \le c |f|_2~~~for ~~all ~~f$$

If $\alpha  =1$ then for $f\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb R)$
we that 
$$ f(x+h)-f(x) =\int_0^1 f'(x+th) h dt$$
that is $$ \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|} \right| = \left|\int_0^1 f'(x+th) dt.\right|$$

Unlike, for the second case applying the above trick twice we have,$$ \left|\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{|h|}\right|  =\left|\int_0^1 f'(x+th)-  f'(x-th)dt.\right|\\ = \left|\int_0^1t\int_0^1 f''(x-th+2sth)h\right| \le |h|\|f''\|_\infty$$

If we assume that
$|f|_1 \le c |f|_2 $  then this leads to 
$$ \|f\|_\infty + \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|} \right| \le  |f|_1  \le c(\|f\|_\infty + |h|\|f''\|_\infty)~~~~\forall ~~h $$

Comment: you shouldn't prove that $c=2$ as the question of OP?

Comment: But in the question he says to prove that $c^{-1}|f|_2\le |f|_1 \le c |f|_2$.

Comment: It is straight forward but I don't see it as irrelevant. Also made your question much more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: Ok sorry it was not appropriate as word to use

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Two questions: 1) Is there any reason why $f\in C_c^{\infty} $ in the statement? You didnt use it or? 
2) Is there a problem for $\alpha =1$?

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Your answer begs several questions: How do you know that $C(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a Banach space with the $|\cdot|_2$ norm? (It's not.) And how do you know that the imbedding is onto? There could be functions $f$ for which $|f|_2 < \infty$ but $|f|_1$ does not exist.

Comment: You are right Now check the new version I have change the argument even the first version was not totally  wrong. Holder spaces a re banach spaces isn't ?